# How to Disable a single reports export feature in ssrs without impacting the export features of other reports?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2014

I have a report in SSRS 2014 where i need to disable the export feature.  The export feature should get disabled only on a single report without impacting the export feature of other reports. This needs to be done in the Reports only as i am using Microsoft Report Browser and not using any other way to access the reports.  Need help.

Comment: may I know what is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: https://www.cleverspeck.com/single-post/2016/08/03/Disable-Export-Options-Per-Report-in-SSRS-2012-2014. take a look at that. I think that's what you want.